# How to create my custom control with event in Mapboxgl?

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox-gl-js

Using the mapboxgl, I added a my custom map control, which can do some special functions,and I refered the office example with basic function. But When I completed codes, I found the event click of button did not work. I have add the stopPropagation function. So how to add click event in the mapbox control?

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoieGlhb2thbmciLCJhIjoiY2lqc2d2NXlyMGhkbHU0bTVtcGNiOWxseCJ9.J5qsX13KKNT1slMGS-MOLg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

class ToggleControl {
  onAdd(map){
    this.map = map;
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    this.container.className = 'my-custom-control';

    const button = this._createButton('monitor_button')
    this.container.appendChild(button);
    return this.container;
  }
  onRemove(){
    this.container.parentNode.removeChild(this.container);
    this.map = undefined;
  }
  _createButton(className) {
    const el = window.document.createElement('button')
    el.className = className;
    el.textContent = 'toggleControl';
    el.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
      e.style.display = 'none'
      console.log(e);
      // e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    },false )
    return el;
  }
}
const toggleControl = new ToggleControl()
map.addControl(toggleControl,'top-left')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the mapbox container positioning style removes mouse events handling ([`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)):

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left, 
.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-right, 
.mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-left, 
.mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

So you need to add the class `mapboxgl-ctrl` ([`pointer-events: auto;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values)) to the container for catching events:

```
this.container.className = 'mapboxgl-ctrl my-custom-control';
```

Or set this CSS-property manually:

```
.my-custom-control {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/Lkes0ch8/ ]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, stdob-- is correct,
by add 'mapboxgl-ctrl' to className solved my problem.
without this, user can not drag the slider bar.

```
    this._container.className = 'mapboxgl-ctrl  mapboxgl-ctrl-group opacityDIV';
```

Top right corner slider is what I created.
[image]

There are 2 way to add mapbox control,

standard way is from mapbox example,

alternative way is works the same

Here is my working code:

[image]